# Extend the Timeout in Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm doing a query in Mongodb from Node JS, but when the query exceeds 20,000 records, the `timeout` runs out.

```
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    try {
     MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("anadb");
      // trae todas las colecciones en un rango de fechas
      var query = {"channel":canal,"createAt":{$gte: new Date(fechaInicial + CONST_CONFIG.CONFIG_BEGIN_TIME), $lte: new Date(fechaFinal + CONST_CONFIG.CONFIG_END_TIME)}};
      dbo.collection("dashboardLogs").find(query).toArray(async function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
          if(result.length > 0){
            response[2] = "true";
          }else if(result.length == 0){
            response[2] = "false";
          }
          response[0] = get_unique_users_web(result);
          response[1] = get_top_functions(result);
          response[4] = get_chatbot_intents_list(result);
          db.close();
          response[3] = await get_report_sac(fechaInicial,fechaFinal);
          // encabezado del archivo de reporte
          var fields = ['CustomerId', 'CustomerName','CaseNumber','RequestSource', 'Comments','Updated', 'PhoneNumber', 'SecondaryPhoneNumber', 'PurchaseValue', 'PurchaseDate', 'ProductName', 'PaymentMethod', 'CustomerEmail'];
          const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser({ fields, withBOM: true });
          var csv = json2csvParser.parse(response[3]); 
          // genera el archivo de reporte
          fs.writeFile('./public/file.csv', csv, function(err) {
              if (err) throw err;
          });


          resolve(response);
      });

    }); 
  }
  catch(err) {
    resolve(err);
  } 
  })
```

I tried adding a timeout to the database query but it still runs out

```
var data = dbo.collection("dashboardLogs").find(query).toArray(async function(err, result) {
....
}

data.timeout = 60000
```

Comment: Have you read this http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/reference/connecting/connection-settings/ ?

Answer (score 0):

can you try to append the socketTimeoutMS=somehighervalue in your mongo connection string while making a connection?